# Converting my date month name(number) to word in a SQL query

Tags: mysql, date

Please help me to convert my query that returns a format of number in months. I want it to be converted as a word like: January.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    MONTH(tbl_check_up.check_up_date) AS datemonths
FROM
    tbl_clinics
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_queue ON tbl_clinics.clinic_id = tbl_queue.clinic_id
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_check_up ON tbl_queue.queue_id = tbl_check_up.queue_id
WHERE 
    tbl_clinics.user_id = 102 
    AND YEAR(tbl_check_up.check_up_date) = 2017
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(tbl_check_up.check_up_date)
```

The output of my query is this:

```
--------------
| datemonths |
--------------
|     2      |
|     4      |
|____________|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 DATE_FORMAT(date_column,'%M')
```

your sql will be like below

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(tbl_check_up.check_up_date,'%M') AS datemonths
FROM
tbl_clinics
INNER JOIN tbl_queue ON tbl_clinics.clinic_id = tbl_queue.clinic_id
INNER JOIN tbl_check_up ON tbl_queue.queue_id = tbl_check_up.queue_id
WHERE tbl_clinics.user_id = 102 AND YEAR(tbl_check_up.check_up_date) = 2017
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(tbl_check_up.check_up_date,'%M')
```

Comment: hello sir can i add something ordering?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `STR_TO_DATE()`. Read about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).